# Is there a way to toggle line numbers for jupyter notebook in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm experiencing difficulties in toggling line numbers for all jupyter notebook cells in vscode. Currently, I'm manually highlighting each cell and enabling line numbers by pressing L. Is there another way for vscode to automatically start numbering each cell?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67372362/836330 possible duplicate